# Retrieve site menus using REST API

Tags: 6, services

I have a site where menus are created using `Site building -> Menus -> List menus -> Primary links -> Add item` option. Some of them have sub-menus under them. I want to retrieve these menus from a REST client. How do I expose these menus from my service endpoint?

I admit I am an absolute beginner in drupal.

Comment: Oops!! We have for 7x http://drupal.org/project/services_menu. May be you can get some idea to back port it for  D6

Comment: @DineshKumar: Yeah, I've checked. A really nice project! Unfortunately no release for 6x, and I needed a quick solution right now........